# How to get Spring RabbitMQ to create a new Queue?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp

In my (limited) experience with rabbit-mq, if you create a new listener for a queue that doesn't exist yet, the queue is automatically created. I'm trying to use the Spring AMQP project with rabbit-mq to set up a listener, and I'm getting an error instead. This is my xml config:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" host="172.16.45.1" username="test" password="password" />

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"  >
    <rabbit:listener ref="testQueueListener" queue-names="test" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="testQueueListener" class="com.levelsbeyond.rabbit.TestQueueListener"> 
</bean>
```

I get this in my RabbitMq logs:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 3-May-2013::23:17:24 ===
connection <0.1652.0>, channel 1 - soft error:
{amqp_error,not_found,"no queue 'test' in vhost '/'",'queue.declare'}
```

And a similar error from AMQP:

```
2013-05-03 23:17:24,059 ERROR [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1) - Consumer received fatal exception on startup
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.FatalListenerStartupException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
```

It would seem from the stack trace that the queue is getting created in a "passive" mode- Can anyone point out how I would create the queue not using the passive mode so I don't see this error? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What seemed to resolve my issue was adding an admin. Here is my xml:

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"  >
    <rabbit:listener ref="orderQueueListener" queues="test.order" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:queue name="test.order"></rabbit:queue>

<rabbit:admin id="amqpAdmin" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>

<bean id="orderQueueListener" class="com.levelsbeyond.rabbit.OrderQueueListener">   
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes, you have to add a `RabbitAdmin` to your config to auto-declared queues, exchanges, bindings.

Comment: Also, the queue won't be declared until a message is sent to it.

Comment: It worked in Java annotation mode too: adding an autowired `AmqpAdmin` and declaring the queue with the dedicated method autocreates the queue when not present !

Comment: Using the rabbit:listener element, how can one get rabbit to declare a randomly named queue for use with a fanout exchange?

Answer (score 27):

Older thread, but this still shows up pretty high on Google, so here's some newer information:

### 2015-11-23

Since **Spring 4.2.x** with Spring-Messaging and **Spring-Amqp 1.4.5.RELEASE** and **Spring-Rabbit 1.4.5.RELEASE**, declaring exchanges, queues and bindings has become very simple through an @Configuration class some annotations:

```
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:rabbitMq.properties")
})
public class RabbitMqConfig {    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMqConfig.class);

    @Value("${rabbitmq.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.port:5672}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(host, port);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);

        logger.info("Creating connection factory with: " + username + "@" + host + ":" + port);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Required for executing adminstration functions against an AMQP Broker
     */
    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    /**
     * This queue will be declared. This means it will be created if it does not exist. Once declared, you can do something
     * like the following:
     * 
     * @RabbitListener(queues = "#{@myDurableQueue}")
     * @Transactional
     * public void handleMyDurableQueueMessage(CustomDurableDto myMessage) {
     *    // Anything you want! This can also return a non-void which will queue it back in to the queue attached to @RabbitListener
     * }
     */
    @Bean
    public Queue myDurableQueue() {
        // This queue has the following properties:
        // name: my_durable
        // durable: true
        // exclusive: false
        // auto_delete: false
        return new Queue("my_durable", true, false, false);
    }

    /**
     * The following is a complete declaration of an exchange, a queue and a exchange-queue binding
     */
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange emailExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("email", true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue inboundEmailQueue() {
        return new Queue("email_inbound", true, false, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding inboundEmailExchangeBinding() {
        // Important part is the routing key -- this is just an example
        return BindingBuilder.bind(inboundEmailQueue()).to(emailExchange()).with("from.*");
    }
}
```

Some sources and documentation to help:

1. [Spring annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#async-annotation-driven)
2. [Declaring/configuration RabbitMQ for queue/binding support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbit_admin)
3. [Direct exchange binding (for when routing key doesn't matter)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#_direct_exchange_binding)

**Note**: Looks like I missed a version -- starting with **Spring AMQP 1.5**, things get even easier as you can declare the full binding right at the listener!

Comment: You create beans and create objects again with methods invocation.

Answer (score 10):

As of **Spring Boot 2.1.6** and **Spring AMQP 2.1.7** you can create queues during startup if they don't exists with this:

```java
@Component
public class QueueConfig {

    private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;

    public QueueConfig(AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin) {
        this.amqpAdmin = amqpAdmin;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void createQueues() {
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(new Queue("queue_one", true));
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(new Queue("queue_two", true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you add this after your connection tag, but before the listener:

```
<rabbit:queue name="test" auto-delete="true" durable="false" passive="false" />
```

Unfortunately, according to the XSD schema, the passive attribute (listed above) is not valid. However, in every queue_declare implementation I've seen, passive has been a valid queue_declare parameter. I'm curious to see whether that will work or whether they plan to support it in future.

Here is the full list of options for a queue declaration:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#class.queue

And here is the full XSD for the spring rabbit schema (with comments included):
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error that the "passive" attribute isn't allowed in the queue element on startup. It is weird that the "declare" method takes the passive argument, but I can't seem to define it in xml.

Comment: Sorry I'm being dense- I don't see what I'm missing. I see you're saying it's not valid xml according to the xsd and I can ignore the error eclipse gives me- but I actually get a runtime error as well.

Comment: That's okay. My middle name is dense. :-)  I think we're saying the same thing. IMHO, the above passive parameter should be present if it's a full rabbit interface. Spring RabbitMQ is missing it. I would file a bug report with them and link back to this question in your bug report. They may know something that we're both missing or it may just be a legitimate omission.

Answer (score 0):

If previously you were using spring-rabbit version <1.6 and now you upgrade to that version or after and you find your queues arent getting created then most likely you could be missing a RabbitAdmin bean. Previous versions dont seem to need that in the context but 1.6 and after do