# Create RabbitMQ queues with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I would like to create rabbitmq queues everytime my Spring Boot application starts (if queues don't exists already).

In the current architecture, we manually create durabl queues using rabbitmq admin. But we want our application, to detect new queues in the configuration and create durable ones if they don't exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Spring RabbitMQ to create a new Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370911/how-to-get-spring-rabbitmq-to-create-a-new-queue)

Answer (score 2):

That is built-in feature of [Spring AMQP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration):

> The AMQP specification describes how the protocol can be used to configure Queues, Exchanges and Bindings on the broker. These operations which are portable from the 0.8 specification and higher are present in the AmqpAdmin interface in the org.springframework.amqp.core package.

Since `amqpAdmin` bean is auto-configured by Spring Boot, you only need to declare particular `@Bean`s for `Queue`s, `Exchange`s and `Binding`s between them.

Comment: need an example, since mine doesnt create

Comment: Here is one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-amqp

Comment: somewhere I read you have to create RabbitAdmin bean explicitely? I dont create it and right now my queues are not created automatically

Comment: Please, pay attention that this question is about Spring Boot, which auto-configure a `RabbitAdmin` for you. Otherwise, please, follow the mentioned docs and explicitly declare bean for it. Anyway this turns out to its own SO thread...

Comment: I use spring boot and cloud foundry - I ll add a new question

Comment: I think you also use Cloud Connectors which seems for me disable Spring AMQP auto-configuration. Therefore a `RabbitAdmin` should be created explicitly.