# Connecting to queue or creating on non-existence in spring-rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring Boot with spring-rabbitmq. My connection factory is configured in `application.properties` and it seems to be nice.

My aim is: **during** start check if exists queue if specific name, and in case of absence create such queue.   I am not sure how to deal with it. What beans should I create in config class? From what I read it should be **RabbitAdmin**, however I am not sure about it.  Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Spring RabbitMQ to create a new Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370911/how-to-get-spring-rabbitmq-to-create-a-new-queue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is described clearly in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#broker-configuration):

> The AMQP specification describes how the protocol can be used to configure Queues, Exchanges and Bindings on the broker. These operations which are portable from the 0.8 specification and higher are present in the AmqpAdmin interface in the org.springframework.amqp.core package.

And further:

> When the CachingConnectionFactory cache mode is CHANNEL (the default), the RabbitAdmin implementation does automatic lazy declaration of Queues, Exchanges and Bindings declared in the same ApplicationContext.

So, you should declare `Queue`, `Exchange` and `Binding` beans in your application context and `AmqpAdmin` will take care about their definition on the target Broker.

There must be a note that according AMQP protocol, if entity already exists on the Broker, the declaration is just silent and idempotent.

So, in your case you don't need to worry about queues existence and just provide their declarations as beans in the application context.

Comment: Thats' incredible, spring-amqp is brilliant, every default settings is reasonable and there is easy way to config it.

Comment: Hi Artem, unfortunatly the link at https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration is dead.

Comment: We have an application A that declares it's own queue but another application B listens to that queue from app A because we have Spring's `Queue` on B side it tries to declare it but the definition is different so it fails saying it can't modify the existing queue. How can I disable auto declaration on B?

Comment: Probably your question deserves its own SO thread with more details.