# Spring RabbitTemplate - How to create queues automatically upon send

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using RabbitMQ together with Spring's RabbitTemplate.

When sending messages to queues using the template send methods, I want the queue to automatically be created/declared if it is not already exists.

It is very important since according to our business logic queue names are generated on run-time and I cannot declare them in advance.

Previously we have used JmsTemplate and any call to send or receive automatically created the queue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `RabbitAdmin` and `admin.getQueueProperties()` to see if the queue exists and `admin.declareQueue(new Queue(...))` to add a queue. You should probably keep track of which one's you've already checked/created in order to avoid the overhead on every send.

You can also add exchanges and bind queues to them with the admin.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a RabbitAdmin to automatically declare the exchange, queue, and binding. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370911/how-to-get-spring-rabbitmq-to-create-a-new-queue) thread for more detail. This [forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/130602-rabbittemplate-send-not-throwing-exception-on-non-existing-exchange-and-routing-key) also bit related to your scenario. I have not tried spring with AMQP though, but I believe this would do it.

```
/**
 * Required for executing adminstration functions against an AMQP Broker
 */
@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}
```

Keep coding !