# How to publish message to rabbit MQ(queue details provided at runtime) using springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

How to publish message to rabbit MQ where queue details are provided at runtime.

There are many articles on publishing messages but the queues are being mentioned in application properties file.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean set the queue name at run time you can send messages using `RabbitTemplate` class and `convertAndSend` method. ([reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest_ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#convertAndSend-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-))

Assuming your class is something like this:

```java
@Component
public class MessageSender {
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    ...

}
```

You can add these methods:

```java
public void sendToQueue(String queueName) {
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, "Hello from Spring!");
}
    
public void sendToExchange(String exchangeName, String routingKey) {
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName, routingKey, "Hi exchange!");
}
```

But if you refer to create the Queue itself at runtime then you need an [AmqpAdmin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/AmqpAdmin.html) as `@Autowired` (recommended) or definiting it in every call.

```java
@Autowired
private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;
```

And inside any method you can create a Queue object with desired parammeters (name, durable... anything else)

Something like this:

```java
Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, ...);
amqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
```

If you want to use `@Autowired`you have to create `amqpAdmin` in a `@Bean` like this:

```java
@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(yourConnectionFactory);
}
```

Is also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872274/spring-rabbittemplate-how-to-create-queues-automatically-upon-send)