# Queue listener fails if queue not present Spring-Rabbit

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

We are trying to use spring-rabbit to create a message listener, in our spring boot application. But, we are getting an issue during receiving message if the queue doesn't exist, the application throws an error, which is called as passive declaration.

```
Channel error on connection (172.13.1.3:49352 -> 172.13.1.7:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
message_queue_1_1  | operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: no queue 'add' in vhost '/'
```

What we want is to declare a queue actively, i.e. if the queue doesn't exist, it should be declared inside the mq.

Comment: Post some code. The queue should be created automatically if it doesn't exist. Post some code the listener and configuration.

Comment: Do you declare the queue with the @Bean annotation?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk yes. 
M.Deinum I did not create a custom listener or configuration, I am just using RabbitListener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Spring RabbitMQ to create a new Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370911/how-to-get-spring-rabbitmq-to-create-a-new-queue)

Answer (score 0):

To declare AMQP objects on the Broker automatically from the application, you really need to configure them as beans and also have a special `AmqpAdmin` bean to perform the hard declaration logic. The documentation has all the required explanation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration